# Android app: decrease battery usage

Tags: android, synchronization, battery

I just finished an app that synchronizes its data with a server (runs SyncAdapter on background). I installed it on my phone, let it run on background (I barely used my phone) and I found out that the 23% of my applications' battery usage belongs to my app, so I really need to decrease  its battery usage.

Right now I have the sync time set to 30 seconds. It's a multi-user app and if other users interact with you you get a notification, I can't set a sync time too high (actually I wanted to decrease it until I saw the battery usage).

In each synchronization it ALWAYS asks the server for any changes and checks for changes in the local database. If there are changes in the local database they are sent to server, and if we retrieve changes from the server they are applied to the local database.

Does anybody know about some tips to reduce battery usage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the best that you can do is to implement GCM ([Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/index.html)) using pushing instead of polling.

In this way you will be able to get a "tickle" when something new happened and you will know when ask to the server for datas.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted to post.

Comment: I didn't know about GCM, I'll try to use it. I'll accept your answer as soon as I can. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I've to tell you that I've tried to implement it and I've encountered some difficulties. It's the best approach but not the easiest (at least it wasn't to me).

Answer (score 1):

A network poll each 30 seconds is very aggressive. I recommend you read this article from Google : http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/index.html

However, if you really need to request the network that often, I don't see any magical trick for you...